# $_POST/$_REQUEST will not read past apostrophe

Tags: php, html

I have a `<select>` object in and HTML form in which one of the `<option>`s has a value of `Test's for/ chars`.

The HTML:

```
<option value="Test's for/ chars">TEST'S FOR/ CHARS</option>
```

$_REQUEST and $_POST both print:

`Test`

I have tried escaping the apostrophe which had no effect. I would then get `Test\`.

I am using php 5.4.6.

PHP - generalized

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):?>
    <option value="<?=$row['field']?>" <?=strtoupper($row['field'])?></option>
<?endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Leaving aside the question of grammar (which would solve your problem), have you inspected the element in the browser DOM inspector? It may be that the problem is in the browser's interpretation of your HTML, not in what is received by the server.

Comment: that was pulled from Chrome dev panel...

Comment: can you post your PHP code?

Comment: @Bill.Caffery I've tried that with php5.3.10 and it worked. What is your form's enctype?

Comment: @hek2mgl it is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Comment: @Bill.Caffery Its default, so I used the same.. (Note my answer). I also tested with different site encodings. Are you able to obtain the plain HTTP POST (headers and body) ? e.g using Whireshark or your dev console?

Comment: @hek2mgl not sure how i would do that actually

Comment: @Bill.Caffery Try to install the Firefox Plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ . Should be the easiest way. When having that data it might be easy to answer your question

Comment: @hek2mgl what info are you looking for exactly

Comment: The plain POST data as text. Note, that HTTP is a text protocol. You can post this communication in a question. So answerers can exactly see what PHP sees. If you worry about what data is transmitted it is the place where should start debugging - debugging the communication

Comment: Form Data: ...&locfacility=Test&...

Comment: @Bill.Caffery Can you simply add the whole HTTP POST message to your question?

Comment: @hek2mgl im sorry i cant expose that much data

Answer (score 3):

You can't escape HTML quotes with a backslash.  Try using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)($string, ENT_QUOTES) in your output:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($str) . "\">$str</option>";
```

This function converts special characters into the appropriate HTML entities:

```
The translations performed are:

'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

Comment: The browser should already be escaping special characters when it submits the form.

Comment: Not when it is set as the value of a form item - if the browser's HTML parser is stopping on the quote, it won't have the value to submit.

Comment: @Tim - But why would it stop at the quote? It's a single quote within double quotes!?

Comment: It still should be used for other reasons, though.  If only to make sure `"` itself is escaped.

Comment: @Tim Do you think my answer (I've tested it succesfully without escaping) is just because I use a more forgiving browser? (Firefox 18.0.1 Linux) Btw the single quote is not listed as a special char in HTML

Comment: @hek2mgl I just ran it in ff as well with the same stupid result same browser as you on ubuntu

Comment: That's possible.  Browser implementation sucks.  Escaping the characters is the safest route, IMO.

Comment: also @Tim I did try this and I got the same result only Test is printed

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="Test's for/ chars">TEST'S FOR/ CHARS</option>
```

Need o put escape before any Special Car.
So: `<option value="Test\'s for/ chars">TEST'S FOR/ CHARS</option>`

Comment: I have tried that as I said in the post and I'm left with `Test\`

Comment: -1. backslash escapes mean absolutely nothing to html. escaping in html means encoding as character entities, e.g. `'` -> `&39;`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to change the ' to & #39;

```
<option value="Test&#39;s for/ chars">TEST&#39;S FOR/ CHARS</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example with PHP5.3.10 and it worked out of the box. I used the following example code:

*test.html*:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" action="test.php">
  <select name="test">
    <option value="Test's for/ chars">TEST'S FOR/ CHARS</option>
  </select>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

*test.php*:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['test'];
```

*Output in browser*:

```
Test's for/ chars
```

Comment: ok I took exactly what you have here and ran it myself with the same result you have here yet this one page is acting up.